# How to pass a filename as a variable, from doc1.html to doc2.html, and use this variable in the w3-include-html function

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3.js

Project: Static website

Required Task: To pass a post filename, eg. post1.html, from Doc1.html to Doc2.html, so the post1.html contents can be included in the Doc2.html page.

PART 1

Question: Is the following method the correct way to approach this?

Doc1.html

```
<p>
    <a href="post-page.html?xfilename=post1.html">Article Title</a>
</p>
```

PART 2

Question: How is the variable, xfilename passed to the statement below in?

Currently, I am trying this unsuccessfully.

Doc2.html

```
<section>
    <p w3-include-html=xfilename;></p> 
</section>
```

Comment: `w3-include-html` is pretty awful and **really** not designed to work in this way. I'd scrap it and take a different approach.

Comment: Noted, thanks Quentin.